# every follower data is returning to every post

Tags: laravel, vue.js, relationship, lumen

I'm using lumen and Vuejs in my project. I want to show a feed of the users I'm following. Currently I can follow users, I also get the user data of the post, but with every user data I'm following. It looks like this:

```
{
        "id": 218,
        "user_id": 218,
        "content": "Mein erster Post hier :) Hi!!! ",
        "created_at": "2019-06-19 07:55:27",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-23 09:22:41",
        "follower_id": 235,
        "follows": 1,
        "username": "test", // logged in user
        "email": "test@test.de",
        "avatar": "1563742871.png",
        "owner_post": [
            {
                "id": 235,
                "username": "jetzt",
                "email": "jetzt@jetzt.de",
                "avatar": "1562769150.png",
                "updated_at": "2019-07-21 20:45:31",
                "created_at": "2019-07-10 13:35:05",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 218,
                    "follower_id": 235
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 221,
                "username": "cicek",
                "email": "cicek@cicek.de",
                "avatar": "1563824515.png",
                "updated_at": "2019-07-23 09:22:33",
                "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:04:44"
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 218,
                    "follower_id": 221
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

But what I want is:

```
{
        "id": 218,
        "user_id": 218,
        "content": "Mein erster Post hier :) Hi!!! ",
        "created_at": "2019-06-19 07:55:27",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-23 09:22:41",
        "follower_id": 235,
        "follows": 1,
        "username": "test",
        "email": "test@test.de",
        "avatar": "1563742871.png",
        "owner_post": [
            {
                "id": 235,
                "username": "jetzt",
                "email": "jetzt@jetzt.de",
                "avatar": "1562769150.png",
                "updated_at": "2019-07-21 20:45:31",
                "created_at": "2019-07-10 13:35:05"
            }
        ]
    }
```

My relationships:
Users Model:
I'm using this to count the followers

```
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function followings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
    }
```

Posts Model:

```
      public function ownerPost()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
        }
```

Edited:
My feed query looks like this:

```
      $test = Posts::join('followers', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'followers.follower_id')
                  ->join('users', 'followers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->with('ownerPosts')
                  ->where('users.id', $user->id)
                  ->get();
```

Do you know how I can fix my problem?

Comment: Can you explain what the `ownerPosts` relationship is used for? Functionally, Laravel appears to be doing what you're telling it to do based on that relationship type. I can't understand what you actually want `owner_posts` to do. Is it the user that created the post?

Comment: Yes exactly, it should be user who created the post. Otherwise I just get the id of the user, but I want to show the username, avatar and the post on the feed

Comment: Then you are looking for $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); Not belong to many because that would mean that a post have many owners.

Comment: Yeah I tried that one, but then I got the user data of the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

The way belongTo work and belongToMany are a little bit different like I said in the comment.

So here is an example:

PostsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Posts;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(Request $request) {
        $posts = Posts::with('owner')->paginate(2);
        return response()->json($posts);
    }

}
```

UsersController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Users;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(Request $request) {
        $users = Users::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    }


    public function get(Request $request) {
        $user = Users::with('posts')->find($request->id);
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    public function following(Request $request) {
        $user = Users::with('following')->find($request->id);
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    public function followers(Request $request) {
        $user = Users::with('followers')->find($request->id);
        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

PostsModel:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model {
    /**
     * Table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "posts";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'content',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * Default Timestamps
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * Appends attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [];

    /**
    * Post owner
    */
    public function owner()
    {      
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

UsersModel

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
    /**
     * Table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "users";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'avatar',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * Default Timestamps
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * Appends attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [];

    /**
     * Hidden attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
    * Posts
    */
    public function posts()
    {      
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Posts', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
    * Following
    */
    public function following()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Followers', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
    * Followers
    */
    public function Followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Followers', 'following_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    current_page: 1,
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            user_id: 11,
            content: "And she thought it had fallen into it: there were TWO little shrieks, and more sounds of broken glass. 'What a pity it wouldn't stay!' sighed the Hatter. 'Does YOUR watch tell you my.",
            created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            owner: {
                id: 11,
                name: "Garett Mills",
                email: "aorn@example.org",
                email_verified_at: null,
                avatar: "https://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/?59504",
                created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
                updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
                deleted_at: null
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            user_id: 12,
            content: "Alice's side as she had expected: before she had to leave off this minute!' She generally gave herself very good height indeed!' said the King was the Rabbit was no one could possibly hear you.' And.",
            created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            owner: {
                id: 12,
                name: "Orlando O'Kon",
                email: "jerrold47@example.net",
                email_verified_at: null,
                avatar: "https://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/?61627",
                created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
                updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
                deleted_at: null
            }
        }
    ],
    first_page_url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/posts?page=1",
    from: 1,
    last_page: 5,
    last_page_url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/posts?page=5",
    next_page_url: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/posts?page=2",
    path: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/posts",
    per_page: 2,
    prev_page_url: null,
    to: 2,
    total: 10
}
```

The data was generated using factories and faker library.

So in this example you will find index call for posts that will get all your posts with their owners and index for user will pull all users.

If you use user get it will pull the user with their posts.

And the response will look like this:

```
    {
    id: 11,
    name: "Garett Mills",
    email: "aorn@example.org",
    email_verified_at: null,
    avatar: "https://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/?59504",
    created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
    updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
    deleted_at: null,
    posts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            user_id: 11,
            content: "And she thought it had fallen into it: there were TWO little shrieks, and more sounds of broken glass. 'What a pity it wouldn't stay!' sighed the Hatter. 'Does YOUR watch tell you my.",
            created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            user_id: 11,
            content: "Alice's side as she had expected: before she had to leave off this minute!' She generally gave herself very good height indeed!' said the King was the Rabbit was no one could possibly hear you.' And.",
            created_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07",
            updated_at: "2019-07-24 15:33:07"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your case you are using **belongsToMany**, this is only correct if you had something that belongs to many instances of other item.

Like for example If many uses have same category, a category will **belongToMany** users and a user will have one category. Then you will need to use **hasOne**.

Please take your time and read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

This documentation may be confuse sometimes but it is correct.

**Update**
Added logic to show users followers and user following.

Your question is more related to the posts, but it should follow the same logic as users.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, and it works, but so I get every post of every user. I tried to join it, and use the ->with('owner) method, to get the posts of my followers, but then I got again the data of the user. So do you know how I can get know the posts of my followers?

Comment: I have updated my response with the followers/following logic for a user perspective, should be similar if you are doing related to posts, you have to pass the follower_id to the posts model as reference to the key so it will grab the posts from the follower_id.